# Inkscape encountered an internal error and will close now

Tags: release-loki

I am using Loki 0.4.1. Whenever I am opening svg file, I am getting this error and Inkscape is crashing
[image]

Please help me out. I tried installing Inkscape but it did not help.

Comment: Have you tried opening a different SVG file? I saw this behaviour with a single file late last year. Upgrading Inkscape fixed it for me.

Comment: @Chris No, but the problem is Inkscape is crashing while opening svg files made by itself. My version Inkscape `0.91-7ubuntu2` is already updated

Comment: That's strange. The SVG I had trouble with was created in Illustrator (though other such files worked fine). In any case, Inkscape 0.91 isn't the latest version; I'm using 0.92.1 (on Arch Linux). It's probably worth upgrading and seeing if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @Chris thanks, your advice help. It turns out there is a bug in 0.91, and 0.91 is what you get from Ubuntu repo, so I installed PPA from Inkscape official website and got 0.92.1 version, which has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a bug in 0.91, and 0.91 is what you get from Ubuntu repo, so I installed PPA from Inkscape official website and got 0.92.1 version, which has resolved the issue.